# Cross Platform Serial port communication in Java?

Tags: java, serial-port

I'm trying to do serial communication with Java. It's hard to believe that there's not some nice, out of the box solution like there is in C#.

I'm looking around the [SerialIO](http://serialio.com/index.php) website, but it's not clear that there's a free .jar I can download to get the functionality I need. (Is it just for sale? I can't find a link for a .jar download of any sort.)

All I need is read/write over a serial port, and setting a baud rate. Nothing fancier than that.

**Edit**: I require that it works on 64 bit Windows and Mac OS X. The Java Communications API only has implementations for Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe RxTx java library is what you are looking for http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: The website is down for some reason. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 3):

SerialIO is a commercial product.

Take a look at [Java simple serial connector](http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/)

> jSSC-0.9.0 Released and available for download.
>   jSSC (Java Simple Serial Connector) - library for work with serial port from Java. jSSC >support Win32 (Win98-Win7), Win64, Linux(x86, x86-64), Solaris(x86, x86-64), Mac OS X 10.5 >and higher(x86, x86-64, PPC, PPC64).

It is licensed under LGPL. We have been succesfully using it  in production for over half a year now. It has shown to be stable, as opposed to RXTXcomm.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html)

> The Java Communications 3.0 API is a
>   Java extension that facilitates
>   developing platform-independent
>   communications applications for
>   technologies such as Smart Cards,
>   embedded systems, and point-of-sale
>   devices, financial services devices,
>   fax, modems, display terminals, and
>   robotic equipment. The Java
>   Communications API (also known as
>   javax.comm) provides applications
>   access to RS-232 hardware (serial
>   ports) and limited access to IEEE-1284
>   (parallel ports), SPP mode.

Answer (score 1):

Purejavacomm is cross-platform and free: http://www.sparetimelabs.com/purejavacomm/purejavacomm.php

Comment: The repository also be found at https://github.com/nyholku/purejavacomm - though most detail is at the mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are probably looking for [Java Communications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) which is an official extension.

Comment: That only works on Linux. Is there a solution available for Windows and Mac OS X?

Comment: You may want to refer to: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page instead then. It's another library that is based on that Java Communications API. Although it looks like more work is involved in setting it up to work on windows.

Comment: It looks like rtxt doesn't support 64 bit Windows.

Comment: Check 64-bit Windows and 64-bit Linux support here: http://www.cloudhopper.com/opensource/rxtx/

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Java Communications API?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html)

> The Java Communications 3.0 API is a
>   Java extension that facilitates
>   developing platform-independent
>   communications applications for
>   technologies such as Smart Cards,
>   embedded systems, and point-of-sale
>   devices, financial services devices,
>   fax, modems, display terminals, and
>   robotic equipment. The Java
>   Communications API (also known as
>   javax.comm) provides applications
>   access to RS-232 hardware (serial
>   ports) and limited access to IEEE-1284
>   (parallel ports), SPP mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am evaluating [java-simple-serial-connector](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector). A cross platform java library to comunicate with serial ports. Tomorrow I'll give more details about my tests.

Event